# How to decompress this zlib compressed response

Tags: ruby, api, zlib, compression

I'm using Charles Proxy to analyse the traffic of a certain app. But the responses seem to have `zlib` compression.

Here's an example of the data it returns:

```
{
   "securityProxyResponseEnvelope":{
      "resultCode":"OK",
      "apiResponse":"{zlibe}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",
      "session":"n3qp6jzHwZkXWSMW3VBF:jitqBjBmlZbrgcEgY7Od",
      "parameters":{

      }
   }
}
```

I've tried Deflating it using:

```
Zlib::Deflate.deflate(data)
# => "x\x9C\x05\xC1E\xB6\xAB0\x00\x00\xD0\x051\xC0)\fq\x97*2+R )\x16\x824\xEF\xFC\xBD\xFF{\xFF\xC8\xB7/\x9B\x7F\xCA\x80k\x93\x17\x99NA\xB5\xD0]\x8E\xAF\x95\xF1*lt\x1C\xAD\xA5\xC0X\xD6\xDB,\xD4/\xAD\x7F\xAA(\xF2Qgg\xEF\xA3k\xD5\x95C\xAE\x80F\xB3u\x8F`n=\xE8\x7F\xA9\x05j\f$\x9ED\x15\xD60\x10\x96K\xBE\n\xAD\x84I\xAD\xB2\xDB\xF8\xF4\x031\xAE\x9D*\x1D\xD4\xA2\x1F\xF8\x02\x18\x99e\xEB\xA9@\xD0\xA6\xDFi7\xBE\xF7Ovy\xF9\xAA%.n9U\x9A@qH\xB5.\xC4a\xE5\xFB\r\x0FY(\xE7)\xDF\xE4\xABx\xB0Q\x02\x86\x1C\x86<\x9B\xCA\xE7\xE5\xBA#\x1F\x12k\xAD\x1C\x1E.\xC61\xE4#\xE3rm\x14\xC5\xF8sl>Hkq\x1D\xB7\xF1\xB7\x9C\xC94\x17N\x94\xF1\xBAV\xA7\xF4\f\x04*b\xB0\x97\x01ur&\xA47r>\x0F\xE0\x1C\xF7\x8E'\xB8\x83\xC1\xA3\xEC\xB5\xA0m\x9E\x81\xC3v\xF6\xFE\xC2\xD0et%\xB1\xC3\x1F\xA6\x15n\x9B_\xA9\xB48\xE7\xA2\xE7SL\a\x0F\xCFg\xF1\"\xC5\xB36\x867-*\fc\xC4\xF7\eDd\xA6\xD8\xDB\xBC\x93R;-|\\\x15\xD0\tbs\xC7]i\x8B\xDDB\x19\xDC\xE4\xC1T$\xC8\xEE\xA5G(7\xB6@\xB0\xBE\xDC\xA6X\xA9\xCD\x9Dp^y]\r\xFD\x91\x90\vC\xE9R\x9F\xE45\xDC\xE3\xDF\x02zV\xFE\xAD\x01\xD0J\xBBr\x0E\x16\bb\xEE\xE2jC\xAFsf,\xBD;34:\xC5\xB1I\x83\xC03\xA7o\xCE\x978:\xF7\xD6,6\x84\xF9\x87\xBC\xA8\x00AT:\x9FZ\x067`\xFC\xEAg\x96\xAF\xE1\xF4\xFE\x0F\xAF\x1D\xB0\xB3"
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I decompress the string in `data['securityProxyResponseEnvelope']['apiResponse']`?

Comment: Is that Base64-encoded?

Comment: The APP author may use additional encrypting method before doing the compression. It's hard (or impossible) to guess what this sequence actually represents.

Comment: @ArieShaw Would it be possible to decompile the .apk file of the app and see how the app decompresses the sequence?

Comment: @tadman, I don't know..

Comment: @narzero You'll have to do some more digging to find out why you're getting that response. It looks Base64 encoded, not a bad choice for embedding binary data in JSON, but a minor nuisance here.

Answer (score 0):

`deflate()` compresses.  You are ending up with the string "{zlibe}9mtdE..." compressed to the zlib format.  You want to use `inflate()` to decompress.

Having said that, if I assume that the characters after "{zlibe}" are Base-64 encoded, I don't find any zlib or raw deflate compressed data in there.  Do you have any documentation on what "{zlibe}" means?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any documentation on what `{zlibe}` means. What if I decompile the .apk file of the app, do you think I could find how the app decompresses the data and write a script to do the same?